# Extract the last 8-6 last lines of a txt file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a lot of files with variable lengths and I want to extract always the last 6-8 lines.I tried using `tail -8 myfile.txt` but it returns the last 8 lines of `myfile.txt`

How can I modify the code to return the lines 8-6 counting from the end?

Comment: Just to clarify the requirement: You want to count back from the last line and return lines number 6 to 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`head`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head) and [`tail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head) commands. For reversing its output, use the [`tac`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tac) command (`cat` backwards) For example this will give the output you want:

```
tac testfile | head -n 8 | tail -n 3
```

`head` will give you the first lines of the file (default: 10 lines, you can change this with the `-n` parameter) and `tail` does the same with the last lines. So doing `head -n 8` gives you the first 8 lines, piping that to `tail -n 3` gives you the last 3 lines, which will then be lines 6 - 8.

For a Testfile with the content

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Line6
Line7
Line8
Line9
Line10
Line11
Line12
```

This will output:

```
Line7
Line6
Line5
```

Comment: This will return lines 6-8 from the beginning of the file, not from its end.

Comment: You are absolutely right, misread the question. Edited the answer to meet the requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tail` to take the last 8 rows, and then `head` to take the first 3 of those:

```
$ tail -8 mfile.txt | head -3
```

Comment: I got a strange error: "head: cannot open `3' for reading: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Iris that was a typo - it should have been `head -3`. I edited and fixed my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk with tac:

```
tac file | awk 'NR >= 6 && NR <= 8'
```

This prints lines 6, 7 and 8 from the output of tac, which prints the lines in the file in reverse.

You can also use a range expression, as suggested by fedorqui (thanks):

```
tac file | awk 'NR == 6, NR == 8'
```

The expression evaluates to true when the first part is true and remains true until the second part is true (did I mention the word "true" enough times?)

Comment: Just for completeness, note `awk 'NR==6,NR==8'` is equivalent to the `awk 'NR >= 6 && NR <= 8'` expression.

Comment: @fedorqui I'm normally a bit scared to use range expressions in case Ed Morton catches me! I think this is a legitimate use case, though. Edited to include your suggestion, thanks.